# Can I serve a js bundle (webpack) from a remote server, or through a script tag that loads from the internet?

Tags: reactjs, bundle

I have a IoT device that's going to have a local copy of a react app. If the app connects to the internet, it should fetch the latest copy of the bundle if available. My plan is to have a local express server handle fetching the bundle and deliver the html w/ it. Then creating a cloud API that I could fetch the bundle from.

But then, I wondered is it possible just to have a async script tag that loads the bundle from somewhere I'm hosting it (s3). Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can. I uploaded my own prod build of react on s3, and then updated the index.html of the prod build to point to the remote version, and then ran it locally. It worked.